# Excel says "No enough memory to create new spreadsheet"

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, temporary-files

I can't make new spreadsheet in Excel because of low memory but i have 20+ gb on my c drive.
In word when starting up, he keeps saying "Can't make file, check var temp"

I think there is something wrong with TEMP var.

Comment: memory has nothing to do with hard disk space.

Comment: @Tetsujin Common mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found answer.
run **regedit** and go to

*"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"* and edit **value** *Cache* to **"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files"**